# Порядок кнопок в проверках

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, очередь-проверок, интерфейс

В проверках "Сообщения низкого качества" первая кнопка - "Выглядит нормально". Т.е. положительное решение.

> [image: Сообщения низкого качества]

В проверках на переоткрытие первая кнопка - "Оставить закрытым". Т.е. отрицательное решение.

> [image: Вопросы на переоткрытие]

Только что автоматически нажал на "Оставить закрытым", будучи в уверенности, что там "Открыть заново".

Нельзя ли унифицировать порядок кнопок?

Comment: С другой стороны, "Оставить закрытым" - положительное решение в том смысле, что вы согласны с закрытием. Не всё так однозначно)

Comment: @Suvitruf Я имел в виду, что левая кнопка имеет смысл "вопросу жить". Как-то так закрепилось из других проверок, а тут оказалось наоборот.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы мог назвать имеющийся порядок как **«меньше изменений»**. То есть, что «Выглядит нормально», что «Оставить закрытым» предполагает ничего не изменять в текущем состоянии сообщений. Опубликованное оставить видимым, закрытое оставить закрытым.

В целом, я не вижу серьёзной причины как-то изменять существующий порядок кнопок. Вот если бы кнопка «Пропустить» появлялась всегда в разных местах, это выглядело бы несколько странным, хотя, возможно, способствовало бы более внимательной проверке ;)